# Is there any difference between And (Condition1 or Condition2) vs And Condition1 or Condition2 in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I want to know. Is there any difference between below two SQL statements.

**SQL Statement 1**

```
Select Id,Code,Name from tbl_student where IsActive=1 
       And (Name like '%'+@Searchtxt+'%' OR Code like '%'+@Searchtxt+'%')
```

**SQL Statement 2**

```
Select Id,Code,Name from tbl_student where IsActive=1 
       And Name like '%'+@Searchtxt+'%' OR Code like '%'+@Searchtxt+'%'
```

I executed both the statements and got result in same time. If there is no difference then what is the better way of writing condition?

Thank you.

Comment: There is a difference. It is called operator precedence. It means some operators bind stronger than others.

Comment: The logic is different in the two `WHERE` clauses.  If they return the same results, that is a coincidence based on the data being used.

Comment: The second query will return students that are not active if the code matches the search text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two conditions are different:

```
where IsActive=1 And
      (Name like '%'+@Searchtxt+'%' OR Code like '%'+@Searchtxt+'%')

where IsActive=1 And Name like '%'+@Searchtxt+'%' OR
      Code like '%'+@Searchtxt+'%'
```

The second is equivalent to:

```
where (IsActive=1 And Name like '%'+@Searchtxt+'%') OR
      (Code like '%'+@Searchtxt+'%')
```

That is, `IsActive = 1` only applies to the `Name` comparison not the `Code`.

Moral:  Use parentheses for your conditions.  They may not always be necessary but until you are really comfortable with boolean expressions, that is the best way to go.